# Wordpress redirects to 302 instead of 301 after installing ssl in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, ssl

i have installed ssl on my site using following code in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

now when i check http://www.redirect-checker.org it shows 302 bad idea.. Please help me changing it to 301.

I have tried this code before:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but it dint work... it showed error site isnt redirecting properly.. so how to solve this problem????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Use of the [R] flag causes a HTTP redirect to be issued to the browser, with a 302 status code being used by default if none is specified.

Comment: Yes, but both -> https www. Ask me if this is not what you want... (with exemples)